# Inserting dom element before render?

Tags: reactjs, components

i am using google maps for the showing a place.But i update the maps address at the componentdidmount stage. And i am using another function for creating the dom element .So when i first enter the maps page , i get error .Because the dom element that maps will be inserted will be inside DOM after the Rendering.
    So without refresh i cant react to maps page .after the refresh ı can .Any idea ?
    (i am using MERN)

```
componentDidMount() {
const {
      match: {
        params: { id }
      }
    } = this.props;

    this.props.getListById(id)
      .then(list => {
        return getLocationAddressAndPlace(
          document.getElementById('__maps'), // This _maps div is not created, will be created after the render.
          list.address.locationName
        )
      })
      .catch(err => {
        toast.error(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Better to use a library for google maps that works with reactjs.

Comment: Thanks will try that .

Comment: Try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps